# Android : ViewPager OnClickListener NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager, onclicklistener

So I Was trying to do something whenever I click on the page.

I did everything I know, implemented the `View.OnClickListener` , and `viewPager.setOnClickListener(this)` , but all I get is the the app crash and I in the logcat I get The NullPointerException , and I was guessing because that I did `button.setOnClickListener(this)` ; it caused the problem ?.

or maybe because I must implement `ViewPager.OnClickListener`, but the IDE gives me the error of duplicate class with `View.OnClickListener`, and I don't want to remove it because I need it for the button.

so am I wrong or right? and if wrong what is the problem and how should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
In your adapter where you return view object or any other view object like image view or button in onInstanciated method use

view.setonClickListner(new Listener(position));

    class Listener implements OnClickListener {
        private int position;


        Listener(int position) {
            this.position = position;
            this.imageView = imageView;
            this.data = data;
        }

        @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

         posSize = position;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + posSize,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly declare which interface you are targeting to, like

`android.view.View.OnClickListener`

A good solution could be adding,

`android:onClick="buttonClicked"` for Button inside xml, and `android:onClick="viewPagerClicked"` for ViewPager inside xml.

These cause method call for respective views,

```
public void buttonClicked(View button) {
}

public void viewPagerClicked(View pager) {
}
```